# Vue debounce slider event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, debouncing

I use `Vuetify`. In a custom component, I have a `v-slider` that emits an input event which then calls `patch` method on API.

The problem is that it sends tons of requests while "sliding". I want to denounce the input to one second.

Inside component:

```
<v-slider :value="uta.requirements_completed_perc"
                    @input="$emit('patch-uta',[uta.id,'requirements_completed_perc',$event])"
                    max="100"
                    min="0"
          ></v-slider>
```

Catching the event:

```
@patch-uta="patchUTA(...$event)"
```

The method for patching:

```
methods:{
        patchUTA(_id, field, val) {
            let self = this;
            var payload = {}
            payload[field] = val ? val : false;
            dx.patchUTA(payload, _id).then(resp => {
                self.showSuccessNotification();
            })
        },
        ... }
```

How can I denounce it using `underscore` `_.debounce` method? Or can I denounce event emitting?

Comment: This doesn't specifically answer your question, but the v-slider component has a start and end event. Wouldn't it be easer to just use one of those instead of the input event? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-slider/#events

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann In fact, that's a very good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
methods: {
  patchUTA: _.debounce((_id, field, val) => {
            const payload = {}
            payload[field] = val ? val : false;
            dx.patchUTA(payload, _id).then(resp => {
                this.showSuccessNotification();
            })
        }, 500) // delay = 500
}
```